# Why are ifconfig's rx/tx bytes reset?

Tags: monitoring

I save every 30 minutes `ifconfig`'s rx and tx bytes for a given interface (ppp) and I see most of the time a steady increase but there are lots of drops/decreased, as if `ifconfig`'s counter was reset from time to time without any notice.

Any idea ? The counters are not close to a 2^n int/long limit either.

I save in my database the uptime of the machine so I am sure there was no reboot.

```
...
data_rx: 2118258
data_rx: 2638183
data_rx: 3177673
data_rx: 3706863
data_rx: 233670
data_rx: 538421
...
data_rx: 10792855
data_rx: 11316207
data_rx: 180722 
data_rx: 725622 
data_rx: 1251739
...
data_rx: 4522068
```

Comment: [Thou shall not use `ifconfig` anymore](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19861454/ifconfig-seemingly-disagrees-with-centos-network-connections-preference/19862736#19862736)!

Try `ip -s link ls $your_interface` instead.

Comment: thanks, will try it and have to wait 2/3 days to validate this solution

Comment: If you are reading from a program you can read `/proc/net/dev` but I'm pretty sure it's Linux only.

Comment: @EliasProbst problem is still there : at roughly 22Mo there is a reset of the counters of `ifconfig` and of `ip`

Comment: @SamK is `ip` giving the info from `/proc/net/dev` ?